# How to Check to See Which Listbox Item Was Selected in TkInter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to figure out how to see if the user picks certain currencies (EUR'S and CAD'S right now) from a Listbox, but when I try to configure the callback of the buttons, it does nothing. Here's what I'm trying:

```
if select_option == 1:
    global btn_convert
    btn_convert.config(command=euro_callback)
elif select_option == 2:
    global btn_convert
    btn_convert.config(command=cad_callback)
```

But this doesn't work. This is my list:

```
select_option = tk.Listbox(window, height=2, selectmode="SINGLE")
select_option.insert(1, "EURO")
select_option.insert(2, "CAD")
```

Am I doing it wrong? Can't I ask if the user selected the option `"EURO"` or `"CAD"` directly in the script?

And all I found when I searched is stuff about regular list, or finding the results of many separate lists (but what I'm trying to figure out is how to get that result and apply a command to a button). When I tried most of these, it just does nothing.

Here's the full code:

```
# Imports the tkinter module, which is vital for the GUI
import tkinter as tk
# Imports the html module from the lxml module. We'll be getting our exchange rates from https://www.bloomberg.com
from lxml import html
import requests

# Makes the window
window = tk.Tk()

# Titles the window
window.title("Currency Converter")

# Makes the window 275 x 200 pixels
window.geometry("275x200")

# Makes the background crimson
window.configure(bg="#900C3F")

# window.wm_iconbitmap("penny.ico")

# Gets the information from Bloomberg Markets
page_euro = requests.get('https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/EURUSD:CUR')
page_cad = requests.get('https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/USDCAD:CUR')
tree_euro = html.fromstring(page_euro.content)
tree_cad = html.fromstring(page_cad.content)

'''
When the "Convert" button is pressed, it'll get the value from the text 
entry where you put in your value you want to convert to (EUROS or CAD 
(Canadian Dollars)), and it'll ask itself; "Is the value all numbers? Or does 
it have characters too?". If it doesn't have characters, it'll run as normal.
If it DOES have characters, it'll inform you that, like; "Whoops! You can 
only put numbers there!"
'''


def euro_callback():
    usd_amount = ent_convert.get()

    if str(usd_amount).isdigit():
        usd_amount = float(ent_convert.get())

        # <div class="price">1.****</div>
        euro_exchange = tree_euro.xpath('//div[@class="price"]/text()')
        euro_exchange = float(str(euro_exchange[0]))

        euro_amount = usd_amount / euro_exchange

        lbl_amount.config(text="Euro Amount: %.2f€" % euro_amount)
    else:
        lbl_amount.config(text="Whoops! You can only put numbers there!")


def cad_callback():
    cad_amount = ent_convert.get()

    if str(cad_amount).isdigit():
        usd_amount = float(ent_convert.get())

        # <div class="price">1.2652</div>
        cad_exchange = tree.xpath('//div[@class="price"]/text()')
        cad_exchange = float(str(cad_exchange[0]))

        cad_amount = usd_amount / cad_exchange

        lbl_amount.config(text="Canadian Dollar amount: %.2f$" % cad_amount)
    else:
        lbl_amount.config(text="Whoops! You can only put numbers there!")

    btn_convert.config(command=callback)


def callback():
    selection = select_option.curselection()[0]
    if selection == 1:
        # euro_callback()
    elif selection == 2:
       # cad_callback()


# The list of available currencies to convert to
# lbl_usd = tk.Label(window, text="Enter the USD ($) here:", bg="#900C3F", fg="#FFFFFF")
select_option = tk.Listbox(window, height=2, selectmode="SINGLE")
select_option.insert(1, "EURO")
select_option.insert(2, "CAD")

ent_convert = tk.Entry(window)

# A blank label, followed by a button, which has the usd_callback() command
lbl = tk.Label(window, text=" ", bg="#900C3f")
btn_convert = tk.Button(window, text="Convert", command=callback)

# A blank label, followed by a label that outputs the EURO amount you would get
lbl2 = tk.Label(window, text=" ", bg="#900C3f")
lbl_amount = tk.Label(window, bg="#900C3F", fg="#FFFFFF")

# Packs (adds) all the labels, entries and buttons into the window
select_option.pack()
# lbl_usd.pack()
ent_convert.pack()
lbl.pack()
btn_convert.pack()
lbl2.pack()
lbl_amount.pack()

# Loops the window, and starts the program
window.mainloop()
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!!

### Edit:

I figured it out! This is the answer I was looking for:

```
def callback():
    selection = select_option.curselection()[0]

    if selection == 0:
        # euro_callback()
        btn_convert.config(command=euro_callback)
    elif selection == 1:
        # cad_callback()
         btn_convert.config(command=cad_callback)


# The list of available currencies to convert to
select_option = tk.Listbox(window, height=2, selectmode="SINGLE")
select_option.insert(0, "EURO")
select_option.insert(1, "CAD")
```

Thanks to Novel and Nelson for helping me!!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the callback is configured once (ideally), when the program boots. The best solution is to use a callback that checks the listbox and can sort out what to do.

For example:

```
btn_convert.config(command=callback)
#...
def callback():
    selection = select_option.curselection()[0]
    if selection == 1:
        euro_callback()
    elif selection == 2:
        cad_callback()
```

Comment: Listbox indexes start at 0. So if there are only 2 items in the Listbox, you should use indexes 0 and 1 instead of 1 and 2